# Crypto miner malware

Tags: malware

I keep finding my server with a 100% CPU usage, and it's an ambiguously named process that's hidden somewhere in the /etc/ folder running under root (always a different folder). The first time I found it I looked it up and confirmed it was a miner, killed the process using `kill -9 PID` and deleted the folder. But I found it another two times and decided to remove it again, but also change the passwords for the account I use to ssh into the server and also for root, but I just found it again.

Is there a way I can identify how a folder got there as there must be something still on my server that periodically checks for these files and if it doesn't find them downloads or extracts them again.

The miner was sending traffic to the following address: ip162.ip-5-135-85.eu which belongs to https://aeon.miner.rocks/

[image: Can't paste text as I had just deleted the contents, but I had a screenshot taken before that]

Comment: please edit in the name of the miner and a  `ls`  of the directory. Most of them use the same method to reactivate.

Comment: One other thing you could do is to route that site, `aeon.miner.rocks` in your `/etc/hosts` file to `127.0.0.1` so that it can't call home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do consider re-installing the server.

Check the following places:

- `crontab -l`  after using `sudo -su`
- `crontab -l` with your admin user
- contents of `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- the directories

  ```
  /etc/systemd/system
  /usr/lib/systemd/system
  /lib/systemd/system
  ```

  for services you do not recognize.

Those will be the main culprits.

aeon-stak-cpuzheck `/bin/` for a `aeon-stak-cpu`.

Do a `locate aeon`. That might pop more directories.

I can not find a malware though. aeon is installed from command line so I expect someone has a connection to your machine.

Comment: Thanks, so I checked my admin user's crontab and nothing was there, checked for root and found an entry related to the miner, I removed it. I also just deleted the recently found files.

I noticed that the owner of some of the files was the user that I use for docker containers. Removed some containers which I don't need to reduce the risk.

What should I look out for in the directories you mentioned?

Comment: sources list could have a ppa where software gets installed from. /etc/rc.local should  be empty or not even there.  The systemd directories are more difficult BUT do a  `grep -r {directory} `  in there. That would be a good start

Comment: "I can not find a malware though. aeon is installed from command line so I expect someone has a connection to your machine."

Me neither, I've changed passwords for the accounts I use and I am trying to see whether I can notice any strange user that may have been created.

Comment: I've just added my user to the ssh_config as allow and restarted sshd, as a precaution

Comment: Good one. You might want to regularly check the auth.log in /var/log too

Comment: Marking as answer, as if I can't get to the bottom of it, I'll just re-install. So far, I've not had the process start again.

Answer (score 1):

So I got to the bottom of it finally.

First of, I had nginx running as root, which was probably the original entry point. Clamscan had found and flagged a file named info.php hidden in /var/www which probably was how they gained access at first.

I kept seeing ssh processes for root@notty, which I didn't know what notty meant at first, and when I looked at netstat it was definitely not any of my sessions. But I've been changing passwords to completely random ones, so it couldn't have been that they knew the passwords. I decided to look at all my user's /home/[user]/.ssh folder and found the same ssh key in the authorized_keys file.

I removed the key, and also changed the user for nginx, and I've not had issues since then.

Comment: Although you don't notice problems, you cannot trust your system anymore. The attackers or attackers botnet could have (automatically) installed any type of backdoor and may attack you again later. If your server got infected once, I would **always** reinstall.

Comment: @pLumo luckily this is just a media server I host for myself which has no personal information, so I'm currently monitoring constantly to see whether I keep getting issues. I will definitely re-install if I keep getting issues. (I sort of took it as a challenge and learning experience too).

Comment: It's good that you tried to find the cause of the attack and how to remove the miner, I think you learned a lot and will be able to make your next setup more secure. But just that you don't notice anything does not mean that there are no more issues. I'm just saying, of course it's up to you ;-)

Comment: Appreciate your input, and considering what I've said above about the importance of what's on it, I'll leave it for now. If I keep getting issues, I'll get a new one, with a new IP as it would probably mean that it's being targeted. Of course it could be that something is still there and I can't see it.